# Trusted host patterns not working

Tags: 8, configuration

I have an issue where I'm trying to make it a "Trusted host patterns" on settings.php. It gets an issue of "The provided host name is not valid for this server."

I have tried many times to get it to work, the issue work with:

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^',
);
```

**But will not get the following to work**

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array(
  '^sandbox\.dev$',
);
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to your screenshot, your hostname is `localhost`, not `sandbox.dev`, so the correct regex would be `^localhost$`